# How to properly debug WebApps deployed in google scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have some experience debugging with google app scripts, but I have encountered myself with this problem since I deployed my first WebApp and haven't been able to find a way to solve it.

The webapp can be accessed by anyone who has the link in order to fill a tiny form, and the information is saved on a google sheets file. The thing is, that after the form is filled out it should redirect you to "Page 1" or "Page 2" depending on one of the answers. The main problem is that when the user is redirected to "Page 1" there is no problem, but when the  redirection is supposed to be made to "page 2" takes a lot of time and sometimes it just does not do it.

The thing is when I test the page as a common user with my google account logged in (the owner's account of the deployment) , I am able to see details about the errors on the app scripts panel, but when any other user enters the webApp I am not able to see further details about the errors on the app scripts panel. I have some code lines such as:

```
console.log('Entered 1st step successfully');
```

to keep track of my process, these logs are indeed registered when I use the WebApp with my google account logged in, but they are not made when the webApp is accessed by any other user, and there are some errors that I just haven´t been able to reproduce, thus corrected them.

Does anyone know how could I properly get the errors information when the users use the WebApp?

I attach an image of the google apps scripts panel which I am referring to.
[App scripts panel view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps1eC.png)

Comment: You can view errors on your script when they are run by other user by going to the Developer Hub `https://script.google.com/home` pick a project and you can see the errors in the last week.

Comment: Hello Cooper, thank you so much, that is actually what I am talking about, when I enter the developer Hub it just says "error" as the image shows but I havo no other details since the drop down arrow does not appear, then I am not able to see any further information

Comment: Well if you want to share the code I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @AR_Tecnologia - could you also let know how exactly have you deployed the app? Referring to the options selected when you **Publish > Deploy as web app...**, what are the options you've used for **Execute the app as:** and **Who has access to the app:**?

Comment: If you could share the relevant lines of code for returning the `HtmlOutput` objects this would be very helpful for dedug, with the HTML of these pages too, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `console.log`  (which executed on the browser and routes the output to the user running the app), use the [`Logger`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger) class so they show up on the [*Execution Transcripts*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#execution_transcript) on the Google platform.

Hope this helps!